# Performance degradation using Azure CDN?

Tags: performance, azure, routes, cdn, trace

I have experimented quite a bit with CDN from Azure, and I thought i was home safe after a successful setup using a web-role.

**Why the web-role?**

Well, I wanted the benefits of compression and caching headers which I was unsuccessful obtaining using normal blob way. And as an added bonus; the case-sensitive constrain was eliminated also.

***Enough with the choice of CDN serving***; while all content before was served from the same domain, I now serve more or less all "static" content from cdn.cuemon.net. In theory, this should improve performance since browsers parallel can spread content gathering over "multiple" domains compared to one domain only.

Unfortunately this has lead to a decrease in performance which I believe has to do with number of hobs before content is being served (using a tracert command):

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert -d cdn.cuemon.net

Tracing route to az162766.vo.msecnd.net [94.245.68.160]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    21 ms    21 ms    21 ms  87.59.99.217
  3    30 ms    30 ms    31 ms  62.95.54.124
  4    30 ms    29 ms    29 ms  194.68.128.181
  5    30 ms    30 ms    30 ms  207.46.42.44
  6    83 ms    61 ms    59 ms  207.46.42.7
  7    65 ms    65 ms    64 ms  207.46.42.13
  8    65 ms    67 ms    74 ms  213.199.152.186
  9    65 ms    65 ms    64 ms  94.245.68.160

C:\Windows\system32>tracert cdn.cuemon.net

Tracing route to az162766.vo.msecnd.net [94.245.68.160]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    21 ms    22 ms    20 ms  ge-1-1-0-1104.hlgnqu1.dk.ip.tdc.net [87.59.99.217]
  3    29 ms    30 ms    30 ms  ae1.tg4-peer1.sto.se.ip.tdc.net [62.95.54.124]
  4    30 ms    30 ms    29 ms  netnod-ix-ge-b-sth-1500.microsoft.com [194.68.128.181]
  5    45 ms    45 ms    46 ms  ge-3-0-0-0.ams-64cb-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.42.10]
  6    87 ms    59 ms    59 ms  xe-3-2-0-0.fra-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.42.50]
  7    68 ms    65 ms    65 ms  xe-0-1-0-0.zrh-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.42.13]
  8    65 ms    70 ms    74 ms  10gigabitethernet5-1.zrh-xmx-edgcom-1b.ntwk.msn.net [213.199.152.186]
  9    65 ms    65 ms    65 ms  cds29.zrh9.msecn.net [94.245.68.160]
```

As you can see from the above trace route, all external content is delayed for quite some time.
It is worth noticing, that the Azure service is setup in North Europe and I am settled in Denmark, why this trace route is a bit .. hmm .. over the top?

Another issue *might* be that the web-role is two extra small instances; I have not found the time yet to try with two small instances, but I know that Microsoft limits the extra small instances to a 5Mb/s WAN where small and above has 100Mb/s.

I am just unsure if this goes for CDN as well.

Anyway - any help and/or explanation is greatly appreciated.

And let me state, that I am very satisfied with the Azure platform - I am just curious in regards to the above mentioned matters.

**Update**

New tracert without the -d option.

Being inspired by *user728584* I have researched and found this article, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2011/03/11/taking-advantage-of-windows-azure-cdn-and-dynamic-pages-in-asp-net-caching-content-from-hosted-services.aspx, which I will investigate further in regards to public cache-control and CDN.

This does not explain the excessive hops count phenomenon, but I hope a skilled network professional can help in casting light to this matter.

Rest assured, that I will keep you posted according to my findings.

Comment: So is your web role pulling data from CDN and delivering that to the user or is your web role simply delivering HTTP pages and the user's browser is requesting static content from CDN?

Comment: The only thing i do in the web-role is to hook up on the appropriate event in the ASP.NET lifecycle; this will add the appropriate caching headers and compression, where all content is "served" from the /cdn folder.

Comment: Cool, I'm very interested my self, look forward to the update!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to state the obvious but I assume you have set the Cache-Control HTTP header to a large number so as your content is not being removed from the CDN Cache and being served from Blob Storage when you did your tracert tests?

There are quite a few edge servers near you so I would expect it to perform better: 'Windows Azure CDN Node Locations'  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg680302.aspx

Maarten Balliauw has a great article on usage and use cases for the CDN (this might help?): http://acloudyplace.com/2012/04/using-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network/

Not sure if that helps at all, interesting...

Comment: Granted, I need to check up on my cache control headers, as I believe i don't accept proxy caching (doooh!). None the less; the hop count is still disturbing - and the response time pr. hop. I will check up on your articles - thanks for sharing, mate.

Comment: Well, I have now updated my CDN with cache-control set to public.
You can see my headers here:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=604800
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2036992d85fc262d9ae5dbdfd7a1eb4a"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 1376
Age: 371
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2012 22:15:44 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 00:09:19 GMT
Expires: Thu, 03 May 2012 22:09:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

You can see, i default for 1 week caching and also send a 304 back in case of "view-source".

Comment: I will keep an eye out on my http://www.cuemon.net/ website after this change; in regards to Azure CDN, files _should_ be left "proxied" for 7 days now.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, after I'd implemented **public caching-control** headers, the CDN appears to do what is expected; delivering content from x-number of nodes in the CDN cluster.

The above has the constrain that it is experienced - it is not measured for a concrete validation.

However, this link support my theory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazurecdn_topic3,

> The time-to-live (TTL) setting for a blob controls for how long a CDN edge server returns a copy of the cached resource before requesting a fresh copy from its source in blob storage. *Once this period expires, **a new request will force the CDN server to retrieve the resource again from the original blob**, at which point it will cache it again*.

Which was my assumed challenge; the CDN referenced resources kept pooling the original blob.

Also, credits must be given to this link also (given by user728584); http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2011/03/11/taking-advantage-of-windows-azure-cdn-and-dynamic-pages-in-asp-net-caching-content-from-hosted-services.aspx.

And the final link for now: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/03/18/best-practices-for-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network.aspx

> For ASP.NET pages, the *default behavior is to set cache control to private*. In this case, **the Windows Azure CDN will not cache this content**. To override this behavior, use the Response object to change the default cache control settings.

So my conclusion so far for this little puzzle is that you must pay a close attention to your cache-control (which often is set to private for obvious reasons). If you skip the web-role approach, the TTL is per default 72 hours, why you may not never experience what i experienced; hence it will just work out-of-the-box.

Thanks to **user728584** for pointing me in the right direction.